# Rails like 'Flash Messages' for Dart

Tags: dart

Is there anything similar to Rails 'Flash Messages' for Dart? Any suggestions are welcome. I'm trying to get a flash message atop the next page but only after an http 'POST' from my form, not on refresh or "GET".

Comment: There's no built-in support for things like this, because Dart is not a framework. It's quite trivial to build flash message support in your application though. It depends on your app. Do you want to output your flash message along with the rest of the HTML (then do it, after checking for `request.method === 'POST'`) and style it with CSS. Alternatively do it like Shannon said, with AJAX and show it dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there anything similar to Rails 'Flash Messages' for Dart?

Unfortunately, no. Your question kind of implies that the server is generating HTML in a response to the client. The Web UI team is pretty focused on client-side applications where much of the logic resides on the client. This is pretty different than how Rails works. Hence, we don't ourselves have a framework like Rails that is focused on generating HTML on the server side. Hence, we don't have a feature like flash messages.

Instead, if you build a client-side application, you can use XHR requests to talk to the server, and then the client can decide what message to show to the user without even reloading the page.